# Reach Router props.navigate

Tags: reactjs, react-router, reach-router

I am trying to use Reach Router to navigate to a `result` url after a form submit. Using `props.navigate` takes be to the desired url, but no component is rendered (I am trying to render `<Result/>` after the query.

To add to the complexity, I would like to pass the `personsResult` prop to `Result`

Here is an outline of my current approach.

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Router>
        <Search path="/" />
        <List path="list" />
        <Result path="result/:query" /> //!
      </Router>
    </div>
  )
}
```

```
const Search = props => {
  const [query, setQuery] = useState("")
  const [personsResult, setPersonsResult] = useState("") //Pass to result

  const handleSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const person = await personsService.get(query)
    setPersonsResult(person)
    props.navigate(`result/${query}`) //!
  }

  return (
    <div>
      ...
      <SearchForm
        handleSubmit={handleSubmit}
        query={query}
        setQuery={setQuery}
      />
    </div>
  )
}
```

I am open to switching to `react-router-dom` if there is a simpler means of solving this.

Comment: If you are open to use "react-router-dom", you can have following switch :
 <Router history={history}>
     <Switch>
        <Route path="/list" exact component={List} props={childProps} />
        <Route path="/search" exact component={Search} props={childProps} />
        <Route path="/result" exact component={Result} props={childProps} />
      </Switch>
  </Router>           

And navigation can be done as :
  this.props.history.push({
    pathname: '/result',
    state: { personsResult: resultData }
})

Comment: What exactlly do you mean by "no component is rendered"? As in you get a blank page, or the url changes, but you don't navigate away from the page, and you're left on the old page? Btw, passing the props should be easy. Just pass an object as the second argument to the navigate call:

```
navigate(`result/${query}`, {personResult: "some value"})
```